# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: java, api, email, outlook, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send an email from Outlook 2010 with javax.mail package but this code didnt work, i'm sure that the mail and the password are correct

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail {

 public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {

    final String username = "something@gmail.com";
    final String password = "something";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "outlook.office365.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("something@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("something111@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Test");
        message.setText("HI");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}}
```

it gave me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

at SendMail.main(SendMail.java:45)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:932)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:843)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:748)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at SendMail.main(SendMail.java:40)
Java Result: 1
```

This is my very first time working with mail api so forgive me for any obvious errors.

Comment: Why are you logging in to a gmail account using outlook's smtp server?

Comment: The guy posted sane-looking code and a full backtrace, with a useful title. No reason to down-vote.

Comment: this is a sample code i found online and i thought that if i put an email and the password it will conect me to the outlook.. As i said i'm new on this, and i'm not familiar with outlook world. So any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: "Outlook" is the application running on your computer; it's irrelevant to what you're doing here.  What you need to know is the name of the server you're connecting to, and the username and password to use with that server.  It looks like you're trying to use a Gmail username, so you need to connect to the Gmail server.  The [JavaMail FAQ has examples for connecting to Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).  If you really want to use the outlook.com server (or the Office365 server, which is similar), the JavaMail FAQ has entries for that as well.

Comment: yes you are right, my mistake there was the server. I found that the host name for google is "smtp.gmail.com" . And now it works! Thank you @BillShannon and everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

1.To apply an outlook account like johnny_fanjinxiang@outlook.com and change username and password variable in the sample code.

2.Modify  'mail.smtp.host' to 'smtp.live.com' in the sample code.